# How to backup database (SQL Server 2008) in C# without using SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backup

I have this code and it is not working but I don't why?

```
try
{
   saveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Server database backup files|*.bak";
   saveFileDialog1.Title = "Database Backup";

   if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand();
      SqlConnection s = new SqlConnection("Data Source=M1-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

      bu2.CommandText = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE LA TO DISK='{0}'", saveFileDialog1.FileName);

      s.Open();

      bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();
      s.Close();

      MessageBox.Show("ok");
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

and I get this error :

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign that SqlConnection object to the SqlCommand - try this code:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string connStr = "Data Source=M1-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
       string sqlStmt = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE LA TO DISK='{0}'", saveFileDialog1.FileName);

       using(SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
       {
           conn.Open();
           bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();
           conn.Close();

           MessageBox.Show("ok");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use your code I get this error messege, http://i44.tinypic.com/5mbhxx.png - What is the proplem?

Comment: Well, does your SQL Server really have a directory `C:\Users\Saleh\Documents` ??? Remember: the backup will be done **on the SQL Server machine** - it will **NOT** be to your own local PC!

Answer (score 5):

You never tell your SqlCommand which connection to use (this is what the error message says by the way, did you read it?). Either set the `Connection` property or use [SqlConnection.CreateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand.aspx) to create the command in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**Backup Sql Server 2008 database in C#(100% correct)**

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
try{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs.conn()); 
    string database = con.Database.ToString(); 
    string datasource = con.DataSource.ToString(); 
    string connection = con.ConnectionString.ToString(); 
    string file_name =data_loaction+database_name;
    --- "D:\\Hotel BackUp\\" + database + day + month + year + hour + minute + second + ms + ".bak";

    con.Close();
    con.Open();                

    string str = "Backup Database  [" + database + "] To Disk =N'" + file_name + "'";// With Format;' + char(13),'') From  Master..Sysdatabases  Where [Name] Not In ('tempdb','master','model','msdb') and databasepropertyex ([Name],'Status') = 'online'";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    int s1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();               
    if (s1 >= -1)
            MessageBox.Show("Database Backup Sucessfull.", "Hotel Management", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    else{
            MessageBox.Show("Database Backup Not Sucessfull.", "Hotel Management", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: This already has an accepted answer and yours doesn't appear to add anything to it.

Comment: never say that a piece of code is **100% correct**! It's either wrong or you will jinx it...